# RegEx split string into words by space and containing chars

Tags: c#, regex

How can one perform this split with the `Regex.Split(input, pattern)` method?

```
This is a [normal string ] made up of # different types # of characters
```

Array of strings output:

```
1. This 
2. is
3. a
4. [normal string ]
5. made
6. up
7. of
8. # different types #
9. of
10. characters
```

Also it should keep the leading spaces, so I want to preserve everything. A string contains 20 chars, array of strings should total 20 chars across all elements.

What I have tried:

```
Regex.Split(text, @"(?<=[ ]|# #)")

Regex.Split(text, @"(?<=[ ])(?<=# #")
```

Comment: And what if there are unpaired special chars? How "this [ string" should be splitted?

Comment: I don't know if this would fix your problem but the problem with your two examples is that in the first `[ ]|# #` only does the or on `]|#` and the second one does the two splits after each other. Also `[` is a special character. You were looking for something like `(?<=(\[ \])|(# #))` though `(?<=[\[#] [\]#])` is probably better.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *matching*, i.e. extracting words, not *splitting*:

```
string source = @"This is a [normal string ] made up of # different types # of characters";

// Three possibilities:
//   - plain word [A-Za-z]+
//   - # ... # quotation
//   - [ ... ] quotation  
string pattern = @"[A-Za-z]+|(#.*?#)|(\[.*?\])";

var words = Regex
  .Matches(source, pattern)
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words
  .Select((w, i) => $"{i + 1}. {w}")));
```

Outcome:

```
1. This
2. is
3. a
4. [normal string ]
5. made
6. up
7. of
8. # different types #
9. of
10. characters
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
var res = Regex.Split(s, @"(\[[^][]*]|#[^#]*#)|\s+")
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5D%7C%23%5B%5E%23%5D*%23%29%7C%5Cs%2B&i=This%20is%20a%20%5Bnormal%20string%20%5D%20made%20up%20of%20%23%20different%20types%20%23%20of%20characters)

The `(\[[^][]*]|#[^#]*#)` part is a capturing group whose value is output to the resulting list along with the split items.

**Pattern details**

- `(\[[^][]*]|#[^#]*#)` - Group 1: either of the two patterns:

  - `\[[^][]*]` - `[`, followed with 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]`
  - `#[^#]*#` - a `#`, then 0+ chars other than `#` and then `#`
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/ydr6TH):

```
var s = "This is a [normal string ] made up of # different types # of characters";
var results = Regex.Split(s, @"(\[[^][]*]|#[^#]*#)|\s+")
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));
```

Result:

```
This
is
a
[normal string ]
made
up
of
# different types #
of
characters
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier using matching approach however [it can be done](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yBtdc4) using negative lookeaheads :

```
[ ](?![^\]\[]*\])(?![^#]*\#([^#]*\#{2})*[^#]*$)
```

matches a space not followed by

- any character sequence except `[` or `]` followed by `]`
- `#` followed by an even number of `#`