# How can I get the clicked word number ( Index ) in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

suppose

```
richTextBox1.Text = "Your description gives people the information they need to help you answer your question."
```

if the Caret position is positioned in the word:

- `information`, I want to get `6`
- `gives`, I want to get `3`
- ...and so on...

Edit:-
thanks to all contributers...

as in the answers there is two logic..

1- select the text from start to the click position then using  (string.Split) to split the words and count them.

```
var start = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
var substring = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, start);
var wordscount = substring.Split(" ,.:;\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
 Label1.Text = wordscount.ToString();
```

2- get the word tokenizing pattern using Regex.Matches...then compare match.Index with the click position

```
        int i = 1;
        string text = richTextBox1.Text;
        string tokenizingPattern = @"(\[[^][]*]|#[^#]*#)|\s+";

        //Create lookup
        List<Tuple<string, int, int>> tokenizedWordLookup = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>();

        tokenizedWordLookup.Add(Tuple.Create<string, int, int>("", i++, 1));
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, tokenizingPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline))
            tokenizedWordLookup.Add(Tuple.Create<string, int, int>(match.Value, i++, match.Index));

        //Return the word index where the selection start is equal to the tokenizing word start
        Label1.Text = tokenizedWordLookup.LastOrDefault(x => x.Item3 <= richTextBox1.SelectionStart)?.Item2.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you show us the expected output for the input

Comment: did you made any efforts to solve this problem? would you care to share them with us ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee if the user click the word "description" as example the output will be 2

Comment: @MongZhu .. I searched if there is a good logarithm or an easy property that can be used... 
currently I'm thinking in getting the sentence from the start to the  CaretPosition then count the words..

Comment: So you are saying that once he clicks on the word, you should return him the word number which is clicked?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee yes thanks for clarification...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        richTextBox1.Click += RichTextBox1_Click;
    }

    private void RichTextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var start = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        var substring = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, start);
        var words = substring.Split(new string[] { " ", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var count = words.Length;

        labelCurrentWordNumber.Text = count.ToString();
    }
```

It will not include the word, when the cursor is in front of a word. if it should, make StringSplitOptions.None

EDIT: I added the "\r\n" for line break also to increase the number for each word. But I thing you will also have to filter out maybe things line , .  ; and so on, to only count words. But this depends on the purpuse you're using this.

Comment: Waw thanks Malior,
this is elegant and working exactly as required

Comment: Glad, that it helps. But to have the "user-approved" you should have a look to the solution from @Kunal Mukherjee and check the link. Using Regex with good rules would be the ideal solution.

Comment: yes, I will try to correct the null reference issue and use It .. thanks for help

Comment: The idea is good. You could use a different array of chars to split the Text, adding some punctuations (peple often forget to insert a space between punctuations) and removing `\r`, because the RTB transforms any CR/LF sequence in just LF (`\n`). Something llike: `var words = substring.Split(" ,.:;\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`. `var count = words.Length;` is useless: you just need `words.Length`.

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as Malior's solution but this also works.

```
private int currentWordIndex()
{
    int currentWordIndex = 1;
    int charactersCounted = 1;

    if (richTextBox1.SelectionStart != 0)
    {
        foreach (Char character in richTextBox1.Text)
        {
            charactersCounted++;

            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(character))
                currentWordIndex++;

            if (charactersCounted == richTextBox1.SelectionStart)
                break;
        }
    }

    else
        currentWordIndex = 1;

    return currentWordIndex;
}
```

Just copy this method and add currentWordIndex() to the richTextBox1_Click event.

Comment: thanks Oliver Dalton ... 
this the code is create may be I has to add new line and other checks to tweak the counting.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this approach:

1. First construct a lookup of the words
2. Find the selection start and end
3. Get the word index

---

You can get the word tokenizing pattern from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767065/7177029) courtesy of @Wiktor Stribiżew.

Here is the complete code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    richTextBox1.Click += RichTextBox1_Click;
}

private void RichTextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var start = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;


    string text = richTextBox1.Text;
    string tokenizingPattern = @"(\[[^][]*]|#[^#]*#)|\s+";

    // Create lookup
    List<Tuple<string, int, int, int>> tokenizedWordLookup = new List<Tuple<string, int, int, int>>();

    int i = 1;
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, tokenizingPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline))
        tokenizedWordLookup.Add(Tuple.Create<string, int, int, int>(match.Value, i++, match.Index, match.Index + match.Length));

    // Find the word index where the selection start is equal to the tokenizing word start
    Tuple<string, int, int, int> foundTuple = (tokenizedWordLookup.Where(x => x.Item3 >= start && x.Item4 <= start).FirstOrDefault()) ?? Tuple<string, int, int, int> foundTuple

    labelCurrentWordNumber.Text = foundTuple.Item2.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Dear Kunal Mukherjee
thanks for help 
I tried your code ... I think it is powerful and fast for a big texts...
but it need some corrections ... 
`string text = richTextBox1.SelectionStart; `
this should change to  ` string text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, start); `

and I get null reference error because of this :- 
`tokenizedWordLookup.Where(x => x.Item3 == richTextBox1.SelectionStart).FirstOrDefault().Item2.ToString();`

Comment: **`string text = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;`**? `SelectionStart` returns an `int`.

Comment: @Jimi fixed the typo.

Comment: Yes, you fixed the typo, but you didn't fix the logic of the process. The Regex will match the starting index of each word, not the index of the current caret position. Thus, `tokenizedWordLookup.Where(x => x.Item3 == richTextBox1.SelectionStart)` will not ever find any matches: the current index is inside the word, not on its boudaries. Also, your `new List<Tuple<string, int, int, int>>();` has more items than the declared one.

Comment: the logic will work only in case I click in the first letter of the word (will be equal to match.Index)

I need to check the richTextBox1.SelectionStart to be >= the current index and < the next index.

Comment: radLabelElement1.Text = tokenizedWordLookup.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item3 >= richTextBox1.SelectionStart)?.Item2.ToString();

this will work for all the text but will not match the last word only

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I ckecked the match.Index value will be more than the richTextBox1.SelectionStart (for the last word)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee thanks for your help... It tried your last correction I will not match the words also (the (match.Index + match.Length) =  match.Index +1 not match.Index + word length...

the logic will work when I add <"" , 1,1> to the list before the loop then check for the last match less than than the current position...
I will share this as edit to my question

regards